# ArangoDB AQL Updating Strange Attribute Names

Tags: arangodb, aql

In arangodb I have a Lookup Table as per below:

```
{
   '49DD3A82-2B49-44F5-A0B2-BD88A32EDB13' = 'Human readable value 1',
   'B015E210-27BE-4AA7-83EE-9F754F8E469A' = 'Human readable value 2',
   'BC54CF8A-BB18-4E2C-B333-EA7086764819' = 'Human readable value 3',
   '8DE15947-E49B-4FDC-89EE-235A330B7FEB' = 'Human readable value n'
}
```

I have documents in a seperate collection such as this which have non human readable attribute and value pairs as per "details" below:

```
{
    "ptype": {
      "name": "BC54CF8A-BB18-4E2C-B333-EA7086764819",
      "accuracy": 9.6,
      "details": {
        "49DD3A82-2B49-44F5-A0B2-BD88A32EDB13": "B015E210-27BE-4AA7-83EE-9F754F8E469A",
        "8DE15947-E49B-4FDC-89EE-235A330B7FEB": true,
      }
    }
}
```

I need to update the above document by looking up the human readable values out of the lookup table and I also need to update the non-human readable attributes with the readable attribute names also found in the lookup table.

The result should look like this:

```
{
    "ptype": {
      "name": "Human readable value 3",
      "accuracy": 9.6,
      "details": {
        "Human readable value 1": "Human readable value 2",
        "Human readable value n": true,
      }
    }
}
```

so ptype.name and ptype.details are updated with values from the lookup table.

Comment: Is your lookup table a single document? How many attributes does it have in total? Do you want to return the desired result, or modify the documents in the separate collection?

Answer (score 0):

This query should help you see how a LUT (Look Up Table) can be used.

One cool feature of AQL is that you can do a LUT query and assign it's value to a variable with the `LET` command, and then access the contents of that LUT later.

See if this example helps:

```
LET lut = {
    'aaa' : 'Apples',
    'bbb' : 'Bananas',
    'ccc' : 'Carrots'
}

LET garden = [
    {
        'size': 'Large',
        'plant_code': 'aaa'
    },
    {
        'size': 'Medium',
        'plant_code': 'bbb'
    },
    {
        'size': 'Small',
        'plant_code': 'ccc'
    }
]

FOR doc IN garden
RETURN {
    'size': doc.size,
    'vegetable': lut[doc.plant_code]
}
```

The result of this query is:

```
[
  {
    "size": "Large",
    "vegetable": "Apples"
  },
  {
    "size": "Medium",
    "vegetable": "Bananas"
  },
  {
    "size": "Small",
    "vegetable": "Carrots"
  }
]
```

You'll notice in the bottom query that actually returns data, it's referring to the LUT by using the `doc.plant_code` as the look up key.

This is much more performant that performing subqueries there, because if you had 100,000 garden documents you don't want to perform a supporting query 100,000 times to work out the name of the plant_code.

If you wanted to confirm that you could find a value in the LUT, you could optionally have your final query in this format:

```
FOR doc IN garden
RETURN {
    'size': doc.size,
    'vegetable': (lut[doc.plant_code] ? lut[doc.plant_code] : 'Unknown')
}
```

This optional way to return the value for `vegetable` uses an inline if/then/else, where if the value is not found in the lut, it will return the value 'Unknown'.

Hope this helps you with your particular use case.

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  My problem is a bit more complicated in that I also need to replace the attribute name e.g. "49DD3A82-2B49-44F5-A0B2-BD88A32EDB13" needs to change to 'Human readable value 1'

Comment: Additionally in your example above the attribute name is given i.e. 'plant_code'.  Where as in my case I receive these GUIDs that need to be mapped from the table.

Additionally the "details" field changes per document e.g. there could be 15 key:value pairs in one document and 3 in the next and 7 in the next etc

Any help would be much appreciated!